# Is $ a^2 x + b^2 y = 0 $ a quadratic equation, where $a, b$ are constants and $x, y$ are variables?

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-forms

Is $$  a^2 x +  b^2 y = 0 $$ a quadratic equation, where $a, b$ are constants and $x, y$ are variables?

Comment: No....it's just linear in the two variables $x,y$.  $a^2,b^2$ are simply constants.

Comment: A quadratic equation has this form: $ax^{2} + bx + c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

No....it's just linear in the two variables $x$, $y$. $a^2$, $b^2$ are simply constants.

(Answer taken from [comment by lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2918847/is-a2-x-b2-y-0-a-quadratic-equation-where-a-b-are-constants-and-x#comment6029724_2918847).)